# View iCloud photos on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, photos

iPhone 5C on iOS 9.1

I've created new albums and uploaded photos from a desktop on the icloud.com "iCloud Photos" page. How would I view these photos from my iPhone?

I have "iCloud Photo Library" on, "iCloud Photo Sharing" on, and I can't really find any other settings for photos. I know iCloud storage is confusing and I still don't understand how it all is supposed to work, but there has to be a way to view these photos, right? I can't even go to icloud.com on the phone because I get a watered down mobile site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The app to use for viewing iCloud photos is the Photos app and not mobile Safari (or any other web viewer).

Tap on Photos and then go to the shared tab. All the photos you have access through over iCloud should be there.

If not, open the settings app and check the settings under iCloud -> Photos and that you're actually logged in with the same Apple ID as you are using to upload the photos. If you can't do that, be sure to invite the AppleID you use on the iPhone to see the shared photos from the uploading account. For most people, the account is one and the same, but you don't have to do it that way if you have reasons.

Comment: I confirmed that my iCloud account was correct and double-checked the shared tab in photos - nothing. I tried rebooting the phone, still nothing. Connectivity to the account works - photos from the phone are showing up on icloud.com, but not the other way around.

Comment: @JoeEnos aah - so you need to troubleshoot the phone to cloud connection. Grr. That's a bit of a goose chase - making sure there's some space on the device, checking date/time, is the server on Apple's end healthy and reachable via your current network connection...

Comment: The photos eventually did show up on the phone - it took over an hour, but they're there now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

When using iCloud Photo Library, it could take a little time for photos to be distributed throughout your devices because the photos have to upload to your account first, and then be added to your devices. Upload speeds are far slower than the download speeds were used to when using the internet. 
Glad to hear that they made it there. Obviously, you have it setup correctly. I think it's a great system. Just make sure you have the proper iCloud room to hold whatever size library you have. And don't worry, it will notify you in advance if you are approaching the limits of your storage.